# Azure Mobile Service Usage in unpublished Application?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

Is there a component in an Azure Mobile service that consumes API calls?

I created an Azure Mobile Service for an application that is still in Development. Its supposed to be an easy way for me to keep an offline sync of my database for a Windows UAP. All I have done so far is import my SQL Database to the mobile service using Visual Studio, haven't even finished implementing the Offline Sync.

My expectation would be to see 0 usage until my app was running, however its constantly showing 50-80 API calls an hour. My only thought is that there is something in Azure consuming API calls and I would like to turn it off.

Comment: I think It's possible those are coming from search engine crawler. Maybe put some logging in a filterattribute to exam what those calls are?

Comment: I cant find any documentation on how to add a filterattribute to the mobile service. I did have the idea to add logging to the tables read script which is what I expected it to call. So far it hasn't logged any of the API calls.

Comment: mobile service is just a web api with some sugar coat around it. You can just refer to web api docs. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your Mobile Service in the Basic or Standard tier?  If so, you can get pings from some automated runners that are checking to make sure your site is working properly. You won't get charged for these API calls, even though they are showing up in the dashboard.